# Python tidy directory path string like cmd.exe

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to emulate the windows command prompt and I have trouble making a CD command tidy and fail-proof and that means paths after I type the CD command must be checked if they exist. And it's because the os.path.isdir accepts paths with multiple backward slashes in-between a directory and a sub-directory and any mixture of upper and lower case letters. I don't mind my CD command accepting the upper and lower case letters as input but when the command changes the directory in which the command prompt works in I'd like the directory displayed before the next command input to be exact as it exists and not as the inputed first parameter of the CD command.

I've overcome the problem of having multiple backslashes by simply stating any path with more than one backslash next to each other is invalid. Is there any way to sort of convert a valid path string into the exact path string including the casings of the letters.

This is probably confusing, sorry :C, tried my best since I can't find how to solve this problem anywhere else.

Edit: In java I'd do something like create a new file with an untidy path name and use a method to get the path name which would be tidy.

Kind Regards,
Aqualight

Comment: Can you rephrase this question? Are you just trying to convert any number of backslashes to one backslash?

Comment: Perhaps [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath), or [`os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath), or [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath).

Comment: the os.path. functions don't seem to fix the lower case and upper case letters. Is it possible to maybe create a python built-in file class instance which will build it's own path string which I can get using a different function. As I've said in java I'd do something like File file = new File(path) and then file.getAbsolutePath() which would return a tidy path.